# NopCommerce : Display best seller products on category home page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I am using NopCommerce. I want to display top 3 bestseller products  on category home page.

I got an idea that on view side `CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines.cshtml` and controller side `CatalogController.cs > HomepageBestSellers` method are used.

I have passed category id as a parameter to HomepageBestSellers method. This category id is passed to BestSellersReport method as parameter.

My question is how can I use category id to display best seller products on category home page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You should create a new action method for bestsellers, in which you will pass category id.
2. In this method you should use the BestSellersReport method like here:

   _orderReportService.BestSellersReport(storeId: _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id, categoryId: categoryId)
3. This new method is very similar to HomepageBestSellers in the CatalogController. See how it's done.
4. And you should create a view, like Views\Catalog\HomepageBestSellers.cshtml and show it where you need.

Comment: can you please tell me how i can join category table with order table using query?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to show best seller product for that particular category only.

Comment: Follow the instructions that I have written. No longer have to do anything. Look at the HomepageBestSellers method - your code should be very similar to it.

Comment: _orderReportService.BestSellersReport(storeId: _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id, categoryId: categoryId). categoryId here indicates that the products are displayed only for the category with this id.

Answer (score 0):

Best Seller Product Code In NopeCommerce

```
#region bestsellers and products

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult BestSellProduct(int categoryId)
        {

            //load and cache report
            var report = _orderReportService.BestSellersReport(storeId: _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id, categoryId: categoryId);


            //load products
            var products = _productService.GetProductsByIds(report.Select(x => x.ProductId).ToArray());
            //ACL and store mapping
            products = products.Where(p => _aclService.Authorize(p) && _storeMappingService.Authorize(p)).ToList();
            //availability dates
            products = products.Where(p => p.IsAvailable()).ToList();

            if (!products.Any())
                return Content("");

            //prepare model
            var model = PrepareProductOverviewModels(products, true, true, categoryId).ToList();
            return PartialView(model);
        }
        #endregion
```